# IHaskell installation via stack problem, Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1

Tags: haskell, jupyter-notebook, console, haskell-stack, ihaskell

I have a problem with installation of IHaskell for Jupyter notebook, my instruction for this proces for MacOS was

https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell

specially

```
brew install python3 zeromq libmagic cairo pkg-config haskell-stack pango
git clone https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell
cd IHaskell
pip3 install -r requirements.txt 
stack install --fast
ihaskell install --stack
```

Everything went well until stack installation where I met this exit failure

```
stack install --fast
```

```
--  While building package zeromq4-haskell-0.8.0 using:
      /Users/mikolaj/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1 configure --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/Users/mikolaj/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/facbc79f1812ecaa43d0389662565ceb62085944fa204232bbf1c0e512f3e783/8.6.5/pkgdb --libdir=/Users/mikolaj/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/facbc79f1812ecaa43d0389662565ceb62085944fa204232bbf1c0e512f3e783/8.6.5/lib --bindir=/Users/mikolaj/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/facbc79f1812ecaa43d0389662565ceb62085944fa204232bbf1c0e512f3e783/8.6.5/bin --datadir=/Users/mikolaj/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/facbc79f1812ecaa43d0389662565ceb62085944fa204232bbf1c0e512f3e783/8.6.5/share --libexecdir=/Users/mikolaj/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/facbc79f1812ecaa43d0389662565ceb62085944fa204232bbf1c0e512f3e783/8.6.5/libexec --sysconfdir=/Users/mikolaj/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/facbc79f1812ecaa43d0389662565ceb62085944fa204232bbf1c0e512f3e783/8.6.5/etc --docdir=/Users/mikolaj/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/facbc79f1812ecaa43d0389662565ceb62085944fa204232bbf1c0e512f3e783/8.6.5/doc/zeromq4-haskell-0.8.0 --htmldir=/Users/mikolaj/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/facbc79f1812ecaa43d0389662565ceb62085944fa204232bbf1c0e512f3e783/8.6.5/doc/zeromq4-haskell-0.8.0 --haddockdir=/Users/mikolaj/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/facbc79f1812ecaa43d0389662565ceb62085944fa204232bbf1c0e512f3e783/8.6.5/doc/zeromq4-haskell-0.8.0 --dependency=async=async-2.2.2-EbxQ7tk0OFk9dJNMtaidSf --dependency=base=base-4.12.0.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.8.2 --dependency=containers=containers-0.6.0.1 --dependency=exceptions=exceptions-0.10.4-9YTZtPQxEYdL6R7qYx7mFz --dependency=monad-control=monad-control-1.0.2.3-BqOxKsUqS1e8EbkW93R1J2 --dependency=semigroups=semigroups-0.18.5-8pPnWqWrcWhEagTFf5Pnk2 --dependency=transformers=transformers-0.5.6.2 --dependency=transformers-base=transformers-base-0.4.5.2-2gGj3LYk7EsEbVllztoDMT --exact-configuration --ghc-option=-fhide-source-paths

Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in zeromq can not find PKG_CONFIG_PATH, after putting before

`` export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:`brew --prefix`/lib/pkgconfig ``

everything works